# How to do an intersection with sxpath

Tags: xpath, guile

What is the best way to do an intersection with sxpath?

For example with the following XML:

```
<root>
  <a category="cat1">
    <b>some text</b>
    <b>foo <c>bar</c> baz</b>
  </a>
  <a category="cat1">
    <b>some other text</b>
    <b>x <c>y</c> z</b>
  </a>
  <a category="cat2">
    <b>foo <c>bar</c> baz</b>
  </a>
</root>
```

How would you use sxpath to select only `b` nodes that have `cat1` parents and `c` children? That is an sxpath that would return:

```
((b "foo " (c "bar") " baz")
 (b "x " (c "y") " z"))
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this [document](https://web.archive.org/web/20070414181503/http://modis.ispras.ru/Lizorkin/sxml-tutorial.html#hevea:sxpathlib),

> The XPath support provided for SXML in SXPath is fully compatible with
>   the XPath Recommendation version 1.0.

So you can try one of the following expressions :

```
(sxpath "//b[parent::a[@category="cat1"]][./c]")
(sxpath "//b[..[@category="cat1"]][./c]")
(sxpath "//b[..[@*="cat1"]][./c]")
```

This should output 2 nodes :

```
((b "foo " (c "bar") " baz")
 (b "x " (c "y") " z"))
```

Comment: Ok I didn't know guile's implementation of sxpath supported strings. :)

Comment: I've edited my answer. The statement comes from SXML documentation. You have to check if guile offers this feature. Keep us updated.:)